# Single ModelForm for model fields, updating just subset at time

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.11. I'm currently solving the following problem:

Currently I'm having multiple ModelForms for a single Model (different forms have different fields of the model in them, e.g. modelForm1 has fieldA, modelForm2 has fieldB, fieldC and fieldD, ...). This is because in the template I need to have the forms in different places (because of the UI).

I was wondering if it is possible to have just one ModelForm with the union of all fields that would update only the fields it receives through request.POST, leaving the others as they are.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that all the fields are non-required and have no validations.

(One possible solution is to encapsulate all the fields in template in the "big" form, but this does not work for me as there are more different non-model forms in the template as well and HTML s cannot overlap or nest.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement multiple save() methods for one modelForm. E.g.

```
def save(self) #standard
   # do the regular save
   super().save()

def save_fieldset1(self)
   # handle some fields
   super().save()

def save_fieldset2(self)
   # handle some other fields
   super().save()
```

Then in *views.py* call each save-method dependent on the target location of your http-POST.

```
# ...
if modelForm.is_valid()
   modelForm.save()
   # ...

# ...
if modelForm.is_valid()
   modelForm.save_fieldset1()
   # ...

# ...
if modelForm.is_valid()
   modelForm.save_fieldset2()
   # ...
```